# Service Fabric local cluster not running

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I have had service fabric working but all of the sudden it has stopped working. I suspect its after the latest visual studio update.

I have reinstalled Service Fabric SDK, Visual Studio 2017 and VC++ redistributable. Deleted actual folders from the disk including C:\SfDevCluster but still no luck.

[image: service fabric]

Any more idea please!!!

-------------------Update------------

```
Do you want to continue [Y/N]?: Y
Removing cluster configuration...
Unable to start fabric host service because System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service FabricHostSvc on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An instan
ce of the service is already running
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricDeployerServiceController.StartHostSvc(String machineName)
Cleaning existing certificates...
Certificates removed.
Stopping all logman sessions...
Cleaning log and data folder...

Using Cluster Data Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Data
Using Cluster Log Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Log

The generated json path is C:\Users\ChirdeepTomar\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5F6C.tmp.json
Processing and validating cluster config.
Create node configuration succeeded
Starting service FabricHostSvc. This may take a few minutes...
```

Running from powershell as admin is getting stuck at that point.

Comment: I expirienced a similar issue, though I don't remember how I fixed it... Have you tried to find SF processes in Task Manager and kill them or reboot?

Comment: Yes done it many times :(

Comment: did you try a reinstall of the tools?

Comment: Yes! Still not working, day 3

Comment: I had a similar issue. It sounds strange but 'Reset Local Cluster' was the thing that helped me.

Comment: I have literally done everything and not working.